# Using Next and Previous Buttons in VBA to Load Userform Given Data in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, button, userform

I am working on a userform in excel-VBA. I am trying to use a next and previous button to cycle through previous entries in a table. The previous button should select the previous row and load it into the userform. The next button should select the next row and load it into the userform as well.The data table has no set length. Below is my attempt at this. I know I have a disconnect between the two buttons function and am not sure how to connect them.  Any help would be greatly appreiciated. I will respond as quickly as I can.

```
Public PrevRow1 As Long
Public cnt1 As Long
Public cnt2 As Long

'Prev Button
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
cnt1 = cnt1 + 1


Sheet4.Activate
PrevRow1 = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1 - cnt1 + cnt2
ComboBox1.Value = Cells(PrevRow1, 1)
ComboBox10.Value = Cells(PrevRow1, 2)
ComboBox2.Value = Cells(PrevRow1, 3)
ComboBox3.Value = Cells(PrevRow1, 4)
ComboBox4.Value = Cells(PrevRow1, 5)
TextBox6.Value = Cells(PrevRow1, 6)
TextBox2.Value = Cells(PrevRow1, 7)
TextBox3.Value = Cells(PrevRow1, 8)
TextBox4.Value = Cells(PrevRow1, 10)
ComboBox6.Value = Cells(PrevRow1, 11)
ComboBox7.Value = Cells(PrevRow1, 12)
ComboBox8.Value = Cells(PrevRow1, 13)
ComboBox9.Value = Cells(PrevRow1, 14)
TextBox5.Value = Cells(PrevRow1, 15)

If PrevRow1 = 1 Then
MsgBox "This is the last entry.", , "Alert!"

CommandButton4.Enabled = False
End If




Me.Label15.Caption = PrevRow1 - 1 & "  " & "of" & "  " &   WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) - 1

End Sub


'Next button
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
Dim i As Long

cnt2 = cnt2 + 1


Dim NextRow1 As Long
Sheet4.Activate
NextRow1 = PrevRow1 - (cnt1 - cnt2) + 3


ComboBox1.Value = Cells(NextRow1, 1)
ComboBox10.Value = Cells(NextRow1, 2)
ComboBox2.Value = Cells(NextRow1, 3)
ComboBox3.Value = Cells(NextRow1, 4)
ComboBox4.Value = Cells(NextRow1, 5)
TextBox6.Value = Cells(NextRow1, 6)
TextBox2.Value = Cells(NextRow1, 7)
TextBox3.Value = Cells(NextRow1, 8)
TextBox4.Value = Cells(NextRow1, 10)
ComboBox6.Value = Cells(NextRow1, 11)
ComboBox7.Value = Cells(NextRow1, 12)
ComboBox8.Value = Cells(NextRow1, 13)
ComboBox9.Value = Cells(NextRow1, 14)
TextBox5.Value = Cells(NextRow1, 15)



Me.Label15.Caption = NextRow1 - 1 & "  " & "of" & "  " & WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) - 1
End Sub
```

---

New Code

```
Public nCurrentRow As Long

Sub UserForm_Initialize()
nCurrentRow = Sheets(4).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
TraverseData (nCurrentRow)
end sub

'Prev button
Private Sub CommandButton14_Click()
Do
    nCurrentRow = nCurrentRow - 1
    TraverseData (nCurrentRow)
Loop Until nCurrentRow = 1 Or Sheets(4).Cells(nCurrentRow, 1).Value = Me.ComboBox12.Value
End Sub

'Next Button
Private Sub CommandButton15_Click()

Do
    nCurrentRow = nCurrentRow + 1
    TraverseData (nCurrentRow)
Loop Until Sheets(4).Cells(nCurrentRow, 1).Value = "" Or Sheets(4).Cells(nCurrentRow, 1).Value = Me.ComboBox12.Value
End Sub

Private Sub TraverseData(nRow As Long)
Me.ComboBox1.Value = Sheets(4).Cells(nRow, 1)
Me.ComboBox10.Value = Sheets(4).Cells(nRow, 2)
Me.ComboBox2.Value = Sheets(4).Cells(nRow, 3)
Me.ComboBox3.Value = Sheets(4).Cells(nRow, 4)
Me.ComboBox4.Value = Sheets(4).Cells(nRow, 5)
Me.TextBox6.Text = Sheets(4).Cells(nRow, 6)
Me.TextBox2.Text = Sheets(4).Cells(nRow, 7)
Me.TextBox3.Value = Sheets(4).Cells(nRow, 8)
Me.TextBox4.Value = Sheets(4).Cells(nRow, 10)
Me.ComboBox6.Value = Sheets(4).Cells(nRow, 11)
Me.ComboBox7.Value = Sheets(4).Cells(nRow, 12)
Me.ComboBox8.Value = Sheets(4).Cells(nRow, 13)
Me.ComboBox9.Value = Sheets(4).Cells(nRow, 14)
Me.TextBox5.Value = Sheets(4).Cells(nRow, 15)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having a difficult time determining what `cnt1 and`cnt2 refer to.

In my opinion, you only need one publicly declared variable used to reference the row of data that is loaded into the table. That variable should be set once the userform is loaded based on desired behavior. For example, the userform loads with data from the last row.

Check the below code as a basis and let me know if it helps at all:

```
    Public nCurrentRow As Long

Private Sub cmdNext_Click()
    Do
        nCurrentRow = nCurrentRow + 1
        TraverseData (nCurrentRow)
    Loop Until Sheet1.Cells(nCurrentRow, 1).Value = "" Or Sheet1.Cells(nCurrentRow, 1).Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value
End Sub

Private Sub cmdPrev_Click()
    Do
        nCurrentRow = nCurrentRow - 1
        TraverseData (nCurrentRow)
    Loop Until nCurrentRow = 1 Or Sheet1.Cells(nCurrentRow, 1).Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value
End Sub    
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
        nCurrentRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        TraverseData (nCurrentRow)
    End Sub

    Private Sub TraverseData(nRow As Long)
        Me.TextBox1.Value = Sheet1.Cells(nRow, 1)
        Me.TextBox2.Value = Sheet1.Cells(nRow, 2)
        Me.TextBox3.Value = Sheet1.Cells(nRow, 3)
    End Sub
```

Needless to say, it must be amended to handle each of your individual userform controls. Additionally, reuse your error checking to confirm that it doesn't traverse into negative rows (you've already done this in your version of the code).

Notice I encapsulated the `TraverseData into its own SubRoutine so you don't have to rewrite it for each button. It really cleans up the data.

Comment: I had been trying yo use the cnt variables to add counters to the buttons, but I will try your method and see if it cooperates with me haha. I'll let you know if I have any issues or if it works first try.

Comment: Cool. Keep us posted. Sounds to me like counters attached to the button are unnecessary.

Comment: Your solution worked very well. Defenitely took out the overcomplications I made. Thank you so much!

Comment: Very happy to hear that. Keep us posted if you have any other issues.

Comment: I've run into another issue. I want to use the Prev/Next buttons again with filtered results so that they only go between the rows that have a specific value in it. This value will be selected in a combobox elsewhere.

Comment: By filtered, do you mean you've used the built-in Excel AutoFilter feature? Or, instead, do you want to jump over rows that do not have the value in the combobox, but the sheet is not being filtered?

Comment: Yes, I just want to jump over rows that do no have the value in the combobox. I am not using the autofilter.

Comment: I've edited the code above, making changes to the code for the previous and next buttons. Now, the code enters a loop that traverses rows until it finds a match to the value in the combobox. Needless to say, adjust the object names to match those in your workbook. Let me know if this works.

Comment: So far it's just pulling the column headers and then erroring out. I'm not sure what would cause that. I don't have a lot of time left today, so I might not get back to it until a week or two. Thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: I added it to the end of the first post.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. In the code above, you have `nCurrentRow2`, but I don't see that variable being declared. I also see a reference to a `TraverseData2` subroutine that is also not being references. Is this correct?

Comment: Sorry, I had been testing something and forgot to take those out.

Comment: Are the loop conditions met? In the current code, it loops until the value in Column A of `nCurrentRow` matches the value in the `ComboBox12`. Is this condition ever met? I created mock spreadsheet/userform to test out the code, and it seems to work fine otherwise.

Comment: Ok I see my issue. I was trying to look through more than just column a. Earlier in my code I have a variable that identifies column selected and I just used that instead of column a. Now it works great. Thank you so much for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public ViewRow as long

'Prev Button
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()

if ViewRow > 1 then 'assumes row 1 is the first row
    ViewRow = ViewRow - 1
    CommandButton5.Enabled = True
    if ViewRow = 1 then
        MsgBox "This is the first entry.", , "Alert!"
        CommandButton4.Enabled = False
    end if
end if


Sheet4.Activate

ComboBox1.Value = Cells(ViewRow, 1)
...
TextBox5.Value = Cells(ViewRow, 15)


Me.Label15.Caption = ViewRow & "  " & "of" & "  " & WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))

End Sub


'Next button
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
if ViewRow < WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) then
    ViewRow = ViewRow + 1
    CommandButton4.Enabled = True
    if ViewRow = 1 then
        MsgBox "This is the last entry.", , "Alert!"
        CommandButton5.Enabled = False
    end if
end if

Sheet4.Activate

ComboBox1.Value = Cells(NextRow1, 1)
...
TextBox5.Value = Cells(NextRow1, 15)


Me.Label15.Caption = ViewRow & "  " & "of" & "  " & WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
End Sub
```

OR

```
Public ViewRow as long

'Prev Button
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()

if ViewRow > 1 then 'assumes row 1 is the first row
    ViewRow = ViewRow - 1
    CommandButton5.Enabled = True
    if ViewRow = 1 then
        MsgBox "This is the first entry.", , "Alert!"
        CommandButton4.Enabled = False
    end if
end if

call populate_row(ViewRow)

End Sub


   'Next button
   Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
   if ViewRow < WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) then
        ViewRow = ViewRow + 1
        CommandButton4.Enabled = True
        if ViewRow = 1 then
            MsgBox "This is the last entry.", , "Alert!"
            CommandButton5.Enabled = False
        end if
    end if

call populate_row(ViewRow)
End Sub

Sub populate_row(thisrow as long)
Sheet4.Activate

ComboBox1.Value = Cells(NextRow1, 1)
...
TextBox5.Value = Cells(NextRow1, 15)


    Me.Label15.Caption = ViewRow & "  " & "of" & "  " &      WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
End Sub
```

The second option lets you make changes to how the data is added to the form without changing both functions.

Comment: Thank you for answering as well, your code helped me with a different area I was struggling with.